# Animating Nested JPanels

Tags: java, swing, animation, jpanel

First off, take a look at this incredible example written in d3.js:  http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/partition.html

[image]

I am trying to emulate something like in Java.  I haven't been very successful.  I have been able to create the GUI, but animating is proving to be difficult.  After playing around with a few things quite unsuccessfully, I think I need some guidance.

EDIT: I'm not sure how to describe the problem, but I'll try. When clicking on a nested JPanel, I would like to focus this panel and expand the contents inside of it to fill the entire window. Much like what you see in the example, if you can view it. For example, when you click on the blue block labeled "vis", this block will focus with all of the contents underneath it. It's very much like a tree, but animated.

I guess I am just stuck on how to design the system in a way that will function as described. I am looking for strategies on how to approach the problem. Please let me know if I need to be more specific.

```
package animation;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class TestAnimation extends JFrame {
    private boolean buttonActive = false;
    private boolean boxActive = false;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestAnimation frame = new TestAnimation();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public TestAnimation() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        ParentObj one = new ParentObj("Vblock", this);
    }
}
```

Here is the class for the parent object that is instantiated:

```
package animation;


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;


public class ParentObj extends JComponent{
    public boolean isActive = false;
    public final JFrame frame;
    public Obj1 compute;
    public Obj1 storage;
    public String name;
    public Obj1 test;

    public ParentObj(String n, JFrame f){
        this.frame = f;
        this.name = n;
        final JPanel panelL = new JPanel();
        panelL.setBackground(Color.blue);
        panelL.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panelL.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                System.out.println(name);
                //startAnimations(box);
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


        JLabel title = new JLabel(name);
        title.setForeground(Color.white);
        title.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        panelL.add(title, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        final JPanel panelR = new JPanel();
        panelR.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));
        panelR.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                System.out.println(name);
                //startAnimations(box);
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


        final JSplitPane panel = new JSplitPane(1, true, panelL, panelR);
        panel.setDividerSize(0);
        panel.setResizeWeight(0.3);
        panel.setBorder(null);
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        compute = new Obj1("Compute", frame ,panelR);
        storage = new Obj1("Storage", frame, panelR);
        test = new Obj1("Network", frame, panelR);
    }

}
```

And finally, the small class for the individual pieces:

```
package animation;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Obj1 extends JComponent{
    public String name;
    public JComponent parent;
    public JFrame frame;
    final JSplitPane panel;

    public Obj1(String n, JFrame f, JComponent p) {
        this.name = n;
        this.parent = p;
        this.frame = f;


        final JPanel panelL = new JPanel();
        panelL.setBackground(Color.blue);
        panelL.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panelL.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                System.out.println(name);
                startAnimations();
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


        JLabel title = new JLabel(name);
        title.setForeground(Color.white);
        title.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        panelL.add(title, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        final JPanel panelR = new JPanel();
        panelR.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));

        panelR.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                System.out.println(name);
                //startAnimations(box);
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


        panel = new JSplitPane(1, true, panelL, panelR);
        panel.setDividerSize(0);
        panel.setResizeWeight(0.3);
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));

        p.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    public void startAnimations(){
        //panel.setSize(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
        ///JRootPane test = panel.getRootPane();

    }
}
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestion on how to produce the correct result or if there is another method of approaching this problem.  Thank you very much!

Comment: I can't run or download your js sample due to firewall restrictions, and so you need to better describe what you're trying to accomplish for those of us with firewalls (really, you should do this regardless and without my needing to prompt you), but having said that, consider using a Swing Timer to drive your animation.

Comment: The link does not work for me as well

Comment: You could take a look a [SlidingLayout](https://github.com/AurelienRibon/sliding-layout), which based on the [Universal Tween Engine](http://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/)

Comment: Also remember, it's the responsibility of the layout manager to layout out the components, so you should probably look at implementing a layout manager to do this work

Comment: Thank you very much!  I'll check it out today and report back.